# Will activating FAN break existing admob ads?

Tags: admob, facebook-audience-network

I have an app running admob ads. I'd like to integrate Meta Audience Network as a bidder, so I've followed the steps outlined for iOS at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/meta.
They mention needing to ad a pod to the project that seems to link the Admob SDK and the FAN one (called "GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook").
This makes me wonder if activating the mediation group now will break the current deployed app implementation, because they will try to get FAN ads without having the SDK ? Or will Admob see that the FAN SDK is not there and therefore not let Meta bid on ads ?

Thanks.